# Pass a cURL command through Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, rest, curl, oracle-apex

I have an Apex Oracle application and I'm trying to integrate a third party module. I need to perform some cURL requests provided by the supplied.

For rest requests, I usually invoke the web server using the method :

```
apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => URL, p_http_method => Method);
```

But I don't know how to do that for cURL ? Does it have to be translated to HTTP request ? Is there any specific way to perform cURL requests in Apex oracle ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Here is the request code :

```
curl -X POST https://xxx/v1/ \
-H "Authorization: Bearer azeoiuqsd" \    
-d "redirectUrl=https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/" \
-d "webhookUrl=https://webshop.example.org/payments/webhook/" # optional
```

Comment: Not sure but I think you could do something like  `apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url=>'https://xxx/v1/', p_http_method=>'POST', p_username=>'Bearer', p_password=>'azeoiuqsd', p_parm_name=>apex_util.string_to_table('redirectUrl:webhookUrl', p_parm_value=>apex_util.string_to_table('https://webshop.example.org/order/12345/:https://webshop.example.org/payments/webhook/');`

Comment: On second thoughts. I think the `-H` needs to be passed as a HTTP header, so you would set `apex_web_service.g_request_headers` first. http://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/Setting-Cookies-and-HTTP-Headers.htm#AEAPI1934